# How to install bouncy castle on Linux machine

Tags: bouncycastle, keystore

When I install bouncy castle on my Linux machine and run following command,

```
keytool -importcert -v -trustcacerts -file "path_to_cert/interm_ca.cer" -alias IntermediateCA -keystore "res/raw/myKeystore.bks" -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath "path_to_bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk16-145.jar" -storetype BKS -storepass mysecret
```

I get the following error:

```
keytool error: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doCommands(KeyTool.java:668)
at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.run(KeyTool.java:340)
at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.main(KeyTool.java:333)
```

Can Someone explain me how to install bouncy castle on Linux machine??

Comment: You're supposed to replace "path_to_*" in the command with real paths to files.

Answer (score 0):

Add BouncyCastle to the Java class path.

Answer (score 0):

Download Bouncy Castle jar from [here](https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html) and add it to your classpath.